# Запрос sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть запрос который нужно чуть чуть подправить.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(
    SELECT batch
    FROM ORACLE.Z_DELIVERY t
    WHERE t.batch LIKE '%{0}-{1}'
          AND t.ORG_ID = 128
          AND t.VBTYP <> 'T'
    ORDER BY PSTNG_DATE DESC
) t
WHERE rownum < 2
```

Мне нужно выбрать первую запись и так что бы ключ в VBTYP был не равен T но как мн сказали в таком виде запрос будет работать не верно. Так как даже если ключ будет равен T но по дате будет выше то запрос мне его и вернёт. Как модифицировать так что бы запрос и по дате отсортировал и без ключа T? Спасибо заранее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Mike помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом.

Comment: @lDrakonl помогите пожалуйста с запросом. Доделать немного нужно)

Comment: *Мне нужно выбрать первую запись* Ну так и используйте `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS` при требуемой сортировке, зачем огород городить с подзапросами и прочей фигнёй?

Comment: @akina а это что за конструкция `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS`? не удалось нагуглить

Comment: > Так как даже если ключ будет равен T но по дате будет выше то запрос мне его и вернёт. Если ключ будет равен Т то он не попадет в выборку и не будет участвовать в фильтрации. Либо вам сказали неверно, либо вы поняли неверно.

Comment: @lDrakonl А это потому, что гуглить при наличии официальной документации - последнее дело. См. `SELECT Syntax` - `row_limiting_clause`, http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA

Comment: @akina спасибо! Справедливости ради стоит заметить, что такая возможность появилась только в 12 версии оракла. На пром средах 12 оракла все еще редкость, так что скорее всего у ТС такая возможность отсутствует.

Comment: @lDrakonl Если автор не уточняет версию, значит, использует актуальную. А если это не так - то он сам виноват, что неспособен грамотно сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @lDrakonl у меня 11g так что да отсутствует.

Comment: @lDrakonl есть ещё проблема в том что поле VBTYP может быть null и при этих условиях у меня такие записи не выберет. Что можно сделать что бы их тоже брало?

Comment: `and    (t.VBTYP <> 'T' or t.VBTYP is null)`

Comment: @lDrakonl и ещё вот что нужно. Опишу более подробнее. Есть 2 записи по одной трубе. Запись с меньшей датой либо с ключом J либо с null в поле VBTYP. А запись с большей датой с ключом T. И если есть запись по трубе с наибольшей записью и ключом T. Значит записи по этой трубе вообще не должно выбрать. А по тем условиям что у меня есть сейчас выберет ту запись по трубе которая с меньшей датой. Как ещё добавить условия что бы записи по трубе вообще не выбрало если запись с наибольшей датой и ключом T в поле vbtyp. Спасибо за помощь заранее.

Comment: @lDrakonl добавил необходимую информацию в виде скрина.

Comment: @Андрей я устал делать за вас вашу работу. Почитайте про то, что такое СКЛ и попробуйте сделать хоть что-то сами. Вы даже не пытаетесь ничего делать сами. Это сервис вопросов и ответов, а не бесплатных решений ваших рабочих задач.

Comment: @lDrakonl спасибо за подсказку. Сейчас почитаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from (              
  select *
  from   ORACLE.Z_DELIVERY t
  where  t.batch like '%{0}-{1}'
  and    t.ORG_ID = 128
  and    t.VBTYP <> 'T'
  order  by PSTNG_DATE desc
) t
where rownum < 2
```

Условие по `rownum` необходимо написать обернув запрос еще раз, так как сначала идет выборка данных, а потом сортировка. Если отсечение по `rownum` добавить во вложенный подзапрос, то в результате вернется 1 строка(строго говоря случайная), к которой будет применена сортировка.

Comment: @Андрей вы бы все же пытайтесь хоть чуть чуть разбираться в том, что копипастите из прошлых вопросов.

Comment: спасибо, вроде разобрался. А ещё хотел по поводу rownum спросить. Не пойму по какому принципу он идёт в запросе. Просто пытаюсь применить его на более простой запрос. Выдаёт ошибку. Вот запрос. `select * from z_delivery
where vbtyp <> 'T'
order by PSTNG_DATE desc
where rownum < 2` Что в запросе не так?

Comment: структура запроса: `select <колонки> from <таблица> where <условия выбора> order by <сортировка>`. Вы перепутали местами `order by` и `where`. Дополню ответ объяснением, почему нужен второй запрос

Comment: А всё понял. Сглупил я. Сделал 2 where. Спасибо.